# Random Trees in OpenCV from python

Tags: python, opencv

according to the docs (open CV version 2.4) I can use random tree ensembles from python (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html)

after importing cv2 I can see the variable cv2.RTree, but it doesn't have any methods or attributes (e.g. the train method).

Where is the package and how can I use it (if at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use random trees from OpenCV in python.  cv2.RTree is the constructor, so you basically just need to say something like:

```
forest = cv2.RTree(...)
```

Where ... is for your arguments.  You may omit these when you just want to run with the default parameters.  At any rate, the *forest* object now allows you to train and predict.  If you look at the help doc using

```
help(cv2.RTree)
```

You'll see that it says:

```
RTrees() -> <RTrees object>
```

And help(RTrees()) gives:

```
class RTrees(StatModel)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      RTrees
 |      StatModel
 |      __builtin__.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __repr__(...)
 |      x.__repr__() <==> repr(x)
 |  
 |  clear(...)
 |      clear() -> None
 |  
 |  getVarImportance(...)
 |      getVarImportance() -> retval
 |  
 |  predict(...)
 |      predict(sample[, missing]) -> retval
 |  
 ....
```

I know it's generally difficult to read the cv2 python docs, but eventually you get the hang of it. Basically, this doc just tells you that RTrees() is going to construct the object and that once constructed, you'll get an object with the methods you're seeking.  So, back to the concrete example, once you've created the forest, you can call:

```
forest.train(...)
forest.predict(...)
```

With your data matrix.  If you need help with the individual methods, you can now ask something like:

```
help(forest.train)
```

Although, the cv2 help docs are often a bit obtuse in python.  If you aren't already using it, I recommend using ipython (http://ipython.org) since it makes the trial process really easy.

Best of luck.

Comment: -1: Not real help If I call 'help(cv2.RTree)' it says: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RTree' Opencv is 2.4.0.